# Laravel Livechat System Database Design

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, message-queue, livechat

Laravel version 7.0, MySQL version 5.8

I am going to design database for livechat system.
Here are related models & tables.

`User` model - `users` table (`id, name, email, address..`)

`Guest` model - `guests` table (`id, name, ipAddress`)

`Team` model - `teams` table (`id, name, image`)

`team_has_users` (`id, team_id, user_id`)

User should be able to send messages to `User`, `Team`, `Guest`.

---

Here are the possible cases that I could think.

- first approach

`messsages` table (`id, content, from_id, to_id, from_model, to_model`) // I think this is insufficient to save read_status for each users.

- second approach

`messages` table (`id, content`)

`message_from_to` table (`id, message_id, from_id, to_id, read_status`)

---

`from_id` will be `id` of either `users` table or `guests` table.

But `to_id` and `read` status is a bit tricky for me.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Can you make your question a bit more specific? Why are those fields tricky?

Comment: Well, Let's say a user sent message to a team. Then all team members should get that message and each team members will get read_status for that message.
And also let's say a user sent message to the other user.
Then that other user will also get message and read_status.
This part is a bit tricky for me and I am not sure which is the best way to tackle all those case. Also, database should be well-designed for Laravel Eloquent Usage. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Models `User`, `Guest` & `Team` look fine too me.

But if you want to track why a user see a `Message`, you need to track it.
To do it, `message_from_to` need a team_id :

```
$table->integer('team_id')->nullable();
```

Wich will be null if it's a directe message, or contain the `Team` id's.

PS : You still need `from_model` & `to_model` into `message_from_to`, or you know if it's for `User` or `Guest`.

---

Here is a better version on the database structure :

```
users
    id
    name
    email
    ...

guests
    id
    name
    ipAdress

teams
    id
    name

(https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)
team_user
    id_team
    id_user

(https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)
messages
    id
    content
    from_id
    from_type
    team_id [nullable]

(https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)
message_to
    id
    id_message
    to_id
    to_type
    read_status
```

`User` & `Guest` should implement the same class.
With eloquent, you could do :

```
$user->messages(); // return all message
$message->from(); // return User or Guest instance
$message->to(); // return User & Guest array
$message->isRead(Guest|User); // retourn boolean
$message->hasTeam(); // retourn boolean
```

Maybe tip : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: So second approach would be better than first one? Of course with `team_id`.

Comment: `$table->timestamp('team_id')->nullable();` why is it `timestamp` ?

Comment: Houps, bad Copy + Paste ... I'm writing a more details response actual.

Comment: Could you please write Eloquent relation too if it's possible?

Comment: Does `Guest` can be in `Team` ?

Comment: No, only users can be in Team.

Comment: thanks. to get `$user->from()` should I use polymorphic relationship?

Comment: Yes, I forgot this thing.